# "Not authenticated" ghost packages

Tags: software-installation, synaptic, malware

I'm trying to reinstall gwaei via synaptic (because all I get is "segmentation fault"). I "completely remove"d the packages.

Now on reinstall, synaptic tells me

[image: not authenticated]

> ### Warning
>
> You are about to install software that **can't be authenticated**! Doing this could allow a malicious individual to damage or take control of your system.
>
> NOT AUTHENTICATED
>
> [two "ghost" packages]

Of course I don't want a malicious individual to damage or take control of my system.

**Specs**

- Ubuntu 15.04
- Three "other software" repositories, none related to gwaei

What's happening?

Comment: As commented below, I ran an update and afterwards the issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open system settings
2. System Settings --> Software and Updates
3. Software and Updates --> Other Software
4. Uncheck all repositories not related to what you are trying to install, then try again.

Comment: Hm... Actually, I decided to see if I could install anything and updated a different package. Afterwards I installed gwaei and wasn't issued a warning. I hope this didn't allow access to the malicious individual...

Comment: @Earthliŋ No, in fact what that probably did was get rid of the malicious repository. Make sure to post what you did as a comment on your question so people can know how they can fix it